# angular reloads controller when using a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My ui route has states like:

```
        .state('projects', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/?username&token",
            templateUrl: "projects/views/Projects.html",
            controller: 'ProjectController'
        })
       .state('projects.mine', {
            url: "mine",
            templateUrl: 'projects/views/ProjectsMine.html'
        })
        .state('projects.all', {
            url: "all",
            templateUrl: 'projects/views/ProjectsAll.html'
        })
```

I made a directive:

```
    app.directive('description', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl : 'projects/views/directives/ProjectDescription.html',
            controller:ProjectController
        }
    });
```

I made two files exactly the same for the state templateUrls where the only difference is that the template of all uses the description directive like:

```
<description></description>
```

and the other one uses the content of the templateUrl for the description directive (copied 1on1) when not using the directive but the content of the templateUrl file the reload dosnt happen.

Everything works fine but when I go to the 'all' route the ProjectController gets reloaded.
The directive looks like:"

```
<table>
  <tr >
      <td><b>name</b> </td>
      <td>{{project.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
      <td><b>owner</b> </td>
      <td>{{project.owner}}</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

the directive is added in an ng-repeat (in 'all' state) :

```
 <div ng-repeat="project in project|filter:searchText">
     <description></description>
 </div>
```

Links to states in my html:

```
    <a ui-sref=".mine()"><button>my projects</button></a>
    <a ui-sref=".all()"><button>all projects</button></a>

    <div ui-view></div>
```

the other one 'mine' uses the content of the directive and dosnt reload the controller.
When going to 'all'  from 'mine' a reload happens when I go from 'mine' to 'all' the controller isn't reloaded

How can I keep everything as it is but avoid the reload of the controller?

Comment: controllers & directives are not persistent. If you want persistent data, use a service

Comment: @lightswitch05 i use a service to get the data. in the controller, hence I use nested states of project to switch between tables. https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/#nested-states--views

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your goal. You want `projects.mine` to inherit from `projects.all`, and apply an extra filter to the list. Not sure how to do that with UI-Router. But this is definitely a UI-Router question. You might want to reword the title and question to clarify this isn't a simple controller & directive question

Comment: @lightswitch05 no i have one page where i use two nested states for different tables like here http://embed.plnkr.co/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7/preview with 'list' and 'paragraph' both of these nested states have different templates. one uses an directive and the other dosnt, the one with the directive makes my controller reload, the one without a directive dosnt. i dont want the controller to reload because the data wont need a reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing

```
 controller:ProjectController
```

fixed it, using controller:'controllerName' causes a controller to be created for every directive created.

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I realized that it binds to parent controller automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link to the route like a function call:

`<a ui-sref=".list()" class="btn btn-primary">List</a>
    <a ui-sref=".paragraph()" class="btn btn-danger">Paragraph</a>`

Comment: Controllers are only alive when their routes are active. When you move off of a directive and route, its controller is removed from scope and is garbage collected. If you do not want a controller to 'reload', then you cannot let it leave scope. You could 'hide' a directive to keep it in scope and not leave its route. Otherwise, the controller will have to reload.

Comment: @ lightswitch05 could you provide a link to that? i got it working by removing the controller syntax from the directive. the whole point of ui-router nested states is that you dont need to create a new controller and can switch parts of you current view.

Comment: Directive controllers and standalone controllers are two different animals. Just a heads up, using standalone controllers in angular 1 can lead to bad design decisions. Standalone controllers have been removed from Angular 2. It would be better practice to have an overall directive (with internal controller) that stays in scope and shares data with child states then to have a overall controller doing the same thing. Glad you were able to figure it out +1

Comment: how does that work for an ng-repeat if you have for example a list with projects you want to loop, and for each project want to show a directive (like <description>). You do need a standalone controller for the ng-repead to hold the projects right?

Comment: This example has a parent directive with a list, and a child directive for each item in that list https://plnkr.co/edit/CnlVxJJyCx2f9RBFXcnc?p=preview